# Unable to configure route for Get in WebApi 2

Tags: asp.net-web-api2

I'm struggling with something very basic. I'm trying to be get a response from my WebApi2 restful service, and I can't.

I have not edited the default WebApi (`WebApiConfig.cs`) route.

This is the controller

```
public class AboutController 
{
    [Route("api/about/{id:int}/{service1}/{service2}")]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Get(int accountId, string mainservice, string secondaryservice)
    {
          //logic
    }
}
```

If I navigate (in a browser) to `http://localhost:58090/api/about` I get the error message `The requested resource does not support http method 'GET'.` I guess this makes sense, as it doesn't match the route (path).

If I update the path to something which matches the signature, such as `http://localhost:58090/api/about/1/a/b` I get the error message `No action was found on the controller About' that matches the request.`

Even if I add `[HttpGet]` to the `controller`, it makes no difference.

As a sanity test, I updated to

```
public class AboutController 
{
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Get()
    {
          //logic
    }
}
```

and it does what is expected. I'm lost as to why adding the parameters has confused things so much.

I'm lost as to what I've done wrong

Comment: Not sure how valuable this is, I've answered it but if any one feels it's best to delete it, I'm happy to do so

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The route must match the parameters

```
   [Route("api/about/{id:int}/{service1}/{service2}")]
   public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Get(int id, string mainService, string secondaryService)
    {
```

The above won't work, because it is expecting to see service1 and service2 based upon the route.

Update as per the example below

```
   [Route("api/about/{id:int}/{service1}/{service2}")]
   public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Get(int id, string service1, string service2)
    {
```